# how to add menu in blackboot theme in yii 1

Tags: php, yii

Here is my code of `view/layout/main.php`

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/user/profile')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->username.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
```

If i will try to add a menu in this theme, then no change will be shown in main website. But if  i hide `'theme'=>'blackboot',` from `config/main.php` then menu will work properly.

Please tell me how can i add the menu .

Comment: have you view folder under theme directory?

Comment: yes i have a folder, but should i change in theme/view/layout/main.php  or in protected\views\layouts\main.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change inside:

```
 theme/view/layout/main.php
```

as you have configured new theme, system will look now under `theme/view/layout/main.php`